# Can I use Indy10 as-is, without installing a package

Tags: delphi, indy10

When I need to move to a new build of Indy 10, the instructions are to remove files in all sorts of places, download, reinstall, etc. Even when the version itself does not change. I get very nervous about this, since things have gone wrong in the past and I am not at all familiar with packages.

I am not using the IDE components. Is it an option in that case to just add the Indy source files to my project and let Delphi do the compilation/linking?

Delphi 10.1 Berlin; Indy 10.6.2 build 5341.

Comment: yes you can simply add the source to your project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You need the packages only if you want to install the components into the IDE.

Simply add the source code to your project(s) and you are ready to go.

I would still make sure to remove any old Indy sources and DCUs from the search path(s) in the IDE to avoid compiling stale sources (in particular: Ancient include files). It has burned me too many times.